# Extracting one node with LibXML

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-parsing, libxml2

This may be very novice of me, but I am a novice at Perl LibXML (and XPath for that matter). I have this XML doc:

```
<Tims
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://my.location.com/namespace http://my.location.com/xsd/Tims.xsd"
    xmlns="http://my.location.com/namespace"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <Error>Too many entities for operation.  Acceptable limit is 5,000 and 8,609 were passed in.</Error>
        <Timestamp>2012-07-27T12:06:24-04:00</Timestamp>
        <ExecutionTime>41.718</ExecutionTime>
</Tims>
```

All I want to do is get the value of `<Error>`. Thats all. I've tried plenty of approaches, most recently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411684/xmllibxml-replace-element-value) one. I've read the docs through and through. This is what I currently have in my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $xmlString = <<XML;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Tims
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://my.location.com/namespace http://my.location.com/xsd/Tims.xsd"
    xmlns="http://my.location.com/namespace"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <Error>Too many entities for operation.  Acceptable limit is 5,000 and 8,609 were passed in.</Error>
    <Timestamp>2012-07-27T12:06:24-04:00</Timestamp>
    <ExecutionTime>41.718</ExecutionTime>
</Tims>
XML

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xmlString);
my $root = $doc->documentElement();
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($root);

$xpc->registerNs("x", "http://my.location.com/namespace");

foreach my $node ($xpc->findnodes('x:Tims/x:Error')) {
        print $node->toString();
}
```

Any advice, links, anything is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try x:Tims/x:Error/text() in your xpath expression?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still came up empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `/` at the beginning of the XPath (i.e. into `findnodes`).

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. You live and learn I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because you use the document element `<Tims>` as the context node when you create the XPath context `$xpc`. The `<Error>` element is an immediate child of this, so all you need to write is

```
$xpc->findnodes('x:Error')
```

or an alternative is to use an absolute XPath which specifies the path from the document root

```
$xpc->findnodes('/x:Tims/x:Error')
```

That way it doesn't matter what the context node of `$xpc` is.

But the proper way is to forget about fetching the element node altogether and use the document root as the context node. You can also use `findvalue` instead of `findnodes` to get the text of the error message without the enclosing tags:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xmlString);

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc);
$xpc->registerNs('x', 'http://my.location.com/namespace');

my $error= $xpc->findvalue('x:Tims/x:Error');
print $error, "\n";
```

**output**

```
Too many entities for operation.  Acceptable limit is 5,000 and 8,609 were passed in.
```