# Perl: Changing html element Label by ID

Tags: html, perl

How does one with perl change an html element's value using the html element's ID. How do you do this in the code.

For example:

```
        <div id="container">
            <form id="form" action="../code.cgi" method="post">
                <label id="lblMessage" class="text">Message</label>
            </form>
        </div>
```

How would I change the label's text in my perl script?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411684/xmllibxml-replace-element-value

Comment: @Robert, That question is actually a more specific case of this one (being limited to XML::LibXML). Furthermore, this question is well phrased and well answered for future reference. If one of two should be closed, I would prefer for it to be the other one (even though the leading answer with >10 votes is mine).

Answer (score 2):

Get an HTML or [XML parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) find the element (e.g., by [XPath expression](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pod)), and remove all its child text nodes, and add a new text node with the text you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_html(location => 'myfile.html');
my $xpath = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
foreach my $label ($xpath->findnodes('//label[@id="lblMessage"]')) {
    $label->removeChildNodes();
    $label->addChild($dom->createTextNode("new text"));
}
```

Caveat: if there are other nodes (elements, like `<b>` or `<span>`) in your label, these get removed as well.

You probably need to add some code to write the modified html back to a file.

Comment: There's a shortcut that could be used here: `$label->appendText("new text");`

Answer (score 2):

I, personally like [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) for this sort of task.

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = <<END;
    <div id="container">
        <form id="form" action="../code.cgi" method="post">
            <label id="lblMessage" class="text">Message</label>
        </form>
    </div>
END

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content( $html );
$root->elementify();  # Become a tree of HTML::Element objects.

my $message = $root->find_by_attribute( 'id', 'lblMessage' )
    or die "No such element";

$message->delete_content();
$message->push_content('I am new stuff');

print $root->as_HTML();
```