# How to set value to a xml node in perl

Tags: xml, perl

In perl, how to set a value to node in xml? I have searched `metacpan` and not found a module related to xml has a method do this.

Comment: There are perl modules like [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML), [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) which can be used to implement this.

Comment: And, [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) also, as commented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58051122/1338382)

Comment: @rprakash Are there any sample code on these modules?

Comment: @rprakash, Don't recommend a module whose own documentation recommends against using it! [Why is XML::Simple "discouraged"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33267765/589924)

Comment: In the DOM model, XML elements don't have a value; they have child nodes, which might be text nodes. Depending on the parser, you might have to remove the elements children, then append a text node.

Comment: @user2799433 XML::LibXML can be seen [here](https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/basics.html)

Comment: @ikegami wasn't aware about the fact that XML::Simple is discouraged in new code.

Comment: [XML::LibXML replace element value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8411684/589924)

Answer (score 1):

[XML::Twig](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) can modify XML, as can many other modules. To say any more, you'd need to explicate your task.

Comment: I am writing a simple perl program to set data into xml file, the data is specified from command line arguments of this program.

Comment: That doesn't really tell me anything more than your original question. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask